# Not able to search uppercase words in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-indices

I have created an Index by specifying an token filter as lower case and analyzer used in Standard. The version of Elastic Search used is 7.

```
"filter": [
      "lowercase",
      "autocomplete_filter"
    ]
```

but when I search for a text let's say Summer, it does not give any result but when I type summer, it fetches the document.

According to what I know the Document will be stored in the way which we have provided. The standard will only make Elastic search to lower case the tokens.

But why only lowercase words are getting searched but not upper or combination of upper and lower.

Below is the mapping and query.

```
{"mappings":{"properties":,"title":{"type":"text"}


"bool" : {
"must" : [
  {
    "terms" : {
      "title" : [
        "SUMMer"
      ],
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
],
"adjust_pure_negative" : true,
"boost" : 1.0}
```

The value of title in Document is **related to summer**.

The searched item is SUMMer.

Comment: Can you please show the exact mapping for that field and query used for search?

Comment: I have edited the question will field mapping and query

Comment: Looking at the mapping, it doesn't seem that it refers to your custom analyzer. Is it complete?

Comment: No custom analyzer is used. Inbuild Standard Analyzer is only used which tokenizes tokens into lowercase